# Facebook Conversion API's Server event is not being tracked in Test Event Tool

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-pixel

I am trying to implement FB CAPI for my business and I set up a Purchase event and now I want to test it via Event Test Tool. I test it for webpage and EventTest Tool is tracking all the browser event but when i tried to track via server event I am not able to see any history in Server Events Tab.
The Request Format is:

**Method:** `POST`

**Postman URL:** [https://graph.facebook.com/{{API_VERSION}}/{{PIXEL_ID}}/events?access_token={{TOKEN}}](https://graph.facebook.com/%7B%7BAPI_VERSION%7D%7D/%7B%7BPIXEL_ID%7D%7D/events?access_token=%7B%7BTOKEN%7D%7D)

**Request Payload:**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "event_name": "Purchase",
      "event_time": 1619508577,
      "action_source": "email",
      "user_data": {
        "em": "7b17fb0bd173f625b58636fb796407c22b3d16fc78302d79f0fd30c2fc2fc068"
      },
      "custom_data": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": "142.52"
      }
    }
  ],
  "test_event_code": "TEST7039"
}
```

**Request Response:**

```
{
  "events_received": 1,
  "messages": [
  ],
  "fbtrace_id": "AQqIVn-TahE83ocCagd4HKB"
}
```

As request response is successful but I am not able to see the event in Event Test Tool's tab?

**Browser Test Events Data:**
[image]
**Server Test Event Data:**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after alot of testing I came to know that UserAgent and IP address are required values to be passed in user data.

**Updated JSON:**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "event_name": "Purchase",
      "event_time": 1619508577,
      "action_source": "email",
      "user_data": {
        "em": "7b17fb0bd173f625b58636fb796407c22b3d16fc78302d79f0fd30c2fc2fc068",
        "client_ip_address": "yourIPAddress",
        "client_user_agent": "your userAgent"
      },
      "custom_data": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": "142.52"
      }
    }
  ],
  "test_event_code": "TEST7039"
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you! Lots of official manuals on this, but real solution, as usual, only on a lonely SO link found somewhere at the bottom of a google search page. Also, Facebook is evil.

Answer (score 0):

same thing happen to me

- and client_user_agent is not something you can write anything , you have to use proper client agent or it not going to show their

### JSON:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "event_name": "Purchase",
      "event_time": 1619508577,
      "action_source": "email",
      "user_data": {
        "em": "7b17fb0bd173f625b58636fb796407c22b3d16fc78302d79f0fd30c2fc2fc068",
        "client_ip_address": "4.4.4.4",
        "client_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0"
      },
      "custom_data": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": "142.52"
      }
    }
  ],
  "test_event_code": "TEST7039"
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30156501)